# How to push both the client side git and server side git project folders together as a one project (api + front end) on github?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, git, github

1. I was having **.git** in server also and in client also means i am **having two git repo **and I want to create on **root git repo and add both of them inside it**.

when I did this node modules also push in git repo and one of folder like client was not accessible.

1. firstly add .gitignore in parallel folder with client and server.
2. paste this code in .gitignore so that server's and client's node_modules folder should not uploaded in git.

[.gitignore](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFovF.png)

3. go inside client and delete git and .gitignore file if present, using rm -rf .git & rm -rf .gitignore or you can directly delete that file.
4. create new repo in github.
5. git init .
6. git add remote origin https://YOUR_GIT_REPO.git
7. git add .
8. git commit -am "commited"
9. git push origin master

Comment: The term you're looking for is "monorepo". There are a number of ways to solve this but you should do some research and find a tool that's right for you. It's not just a matter of having everything in the same repo. You also need to set up how they're built together so they work properly when it's deployed.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.